# Using a GROUP BY statement to sum rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple product sales in different markets, and I need to sum up the totals for each title. To start:

```
mysql> SELECT title, partner_share_currency, us_earnings_usd, cad_earnings_cad 
        FROM raw_financials WHERE title LIKE "%Gamers%";
+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| title  | partner_share_currency | us_earnings_usd | cad_earnings_cad |
+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
| Gamers | USD                    |          3.2500 |           0.0000 |
| Gamers | CAD                    |          0.0000 |           4.0000 |
| Gamers | USD                    |          4.5000 |           0.0000 |
+--------+------------------------+-----------------+------------------+
```

This is what I currently am doing to get the GROUP BY title:

```
mysql> SELECT title, us_earnings_usd, cad_earnings_cad 
        FROM raw_financials WHERE title LIKE "%Gamers%" GROUP BY title;
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
| title  | us_earnings_usd | cad_earnings_cad |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
| Gamers |          3.2500 |           0.0000 |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
```

As you can see, it does not sum the value rows. How would I change the SELECT statement such that it sums up the value rows, to give me:

```
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
| title  | us_earnings_usd | cad_earnings_cad |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
| Gamers |          7.7500 |           4.0000 |
+--------+-----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: `group by` clauses don't do summing. They just say which rows should be 'collapsed' for use in aggregate functions. you still have to tell which fields the `sum()` function (or other aggregate functions) should be applied to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
mysql> SELECT title, SUM(us_earnings_usd) AS us_earnings_usd, SUM(cad_earnings_cad) AS cad_earnings_cad
        FROM raw_financials WHERE title LIKE "%Gamers%" GROUP BY title;
```

`SUM` is a function that will operate on each group when you have that `GROUP BY` clause on your statement.  For more similar functions, see [MySQL aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Comment: How can you group by title and select a non column function (`partner_share_currency`) ?

Comment: This was copied straight out of the question, and I just added in the sum functions.  OP will probably need to group by `partner_share_currency` as well, to get the result as seen in the examples.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that was a mistake -- I'll change the question to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

You need an aggregate `SUM()` to sum your rows. You only have a `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT
  title, 
  partner_share_currency,
  SUM(us_earnings_usd) AS usd,
  SUM(cad_earnings_cad) AS cad
FROM raw_financials 
WHERE title LIKE '%Gamers%'
GROUP BY title, partner_share_currency
```

Note that MySQL will permit you to include only `title` in the `GROUP BY` clause, where most other RDBMS will also require you to list the other non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY`. Specifically here, that's `partner_share_currency`